# displaying the elements of an arraylist

Tags: java, class, arraylist

I am trying to access a toString method from another class in order to print the elements of the array.

```
 info += "Purchases:\n";
 for(int index = 0; index < purchases.size(); index++){
     info += "[" + (index + 1) + "] ";
     info += purchases.get(index).toString();
     info += "\n";
 }
```

I would like the code to access the toString in the Purchases class to print out

```
public String toString(){
    String info;
    DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("$#0.00");

    info= (date.get(Calendar.MONTH) +1) + "/" + date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + "/" + date.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    info += "\t" + vendor + "\t\t";
    info += (formatter.format(amount));

    return info;
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What is the error you're stuck in?

Answer (score 0):

The way you did it is inefficient but it will work.

What is the problem you are seeing?

If you are getting NullPointerException drop the call to `.toString()` as it will do this for you anyway (except withou the NPE)

Comment: it is only printing the amount and I want it to print the date and vendor like it is in the toString method of the purchase class

Comment: It sounds like you have an old version of your Purchase class running. Try to re-compile it. If this doesn't work, place a break point on the first line of the toString() and then debug it.

Answer (score 0):

When you override the toString() method of an object, you dont need to call it in order to work like:

```
myObject.toString();
```

also for printing arrays i recomend to use the enhanced for loop, it is easier.
Example:

```
List<MyObject> mo = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
for(MyObject s: listObject){
   System.out.print(s);
}
```

The example above would work perfectly if MyObject class overrides the toString() method
Note: just imagine that mo is full of objects.

I think you overrided correctly the toString() method the problem is just in your loop. Give a try to the enhanced for loop:

```
for(Purchase p: purchases) {
  System.out.println(p);
}
```

That should do the job

Comment: it won't allow "Purchase p: purchases" it gives type mismatch error cannot convert from Double

Comment: I need more information. Post the code on your Purchase class so i can see the types of each variable. Ill see what i can do.

Comment: @trs: Are you sure that `purchases` is a `List<Purchase>` and not a `List<Double>` or similar?

Comment: I cannot say, bu if i dont see the code where that variable is declared i cannot know what it is. Also i suppose that the overriding he did was done in the class Purchase. I need to see the class declaration and the rest of the code to know what are we dealing with.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `for(MyObject s : mo)` ?